# How to fix a Fragment's xml inner layout position to the bottom of screen in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a Tablayout, viewpager in an Activity(activity_tabs.xml) . Tablayout contains 5 tabs with 5 fragments. The first fragment is fragment_feed.xml, that goes to viewpager and that viewpager is scrollable. I have a Linearlayout(with FAB button) occupying a small portion at the bottom, in that fragment_feed.xml. The problem here is, In that Fragment(First Tab) the Linearlayout is seen placed a little below and when I scroll up it comes to original position, when scroll down, it goes to the below posotion.

Here is my Fragment Xml(FeedFragment.xml)

```
        <FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/totalFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/light_grey"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.authent.authentication.FeedFragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRelative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/askCircleImageView"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_photo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/askCircleImageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/askQuestion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:text="Ask your Question..."
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/askCircleImageView" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/feed_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRelative"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="196dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearReveal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/share_info"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#00ccff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/askBtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:text="Ask a Query"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#ff3300"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/challengeBtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:text="Post a Challenge"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#cc9900"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatBtn"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_nick_name"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Here is my Activities xml(activity_tabs.xml)

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.authent.authentication.TabsActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/customPopupStyle">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tablayout_border"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Layout Screenshots. This is when the layout inflates.
[image: Initial position of layout(FAB button goes below the screen). That FAB button is in a Linearlayout. that means, the whole Linearlayout goes below the screen]

This is When I scroll on. It comes to original position.

[image: This is when I scroll up. It comes to original position]

That FAB button going down exactly the length of Toolbar. And when I scroll up Toolbar hides and FAB button(entire Linearlayout) comes to original position.

How to fix this issue. I want That Linearlayout(containing FAB button) at a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to use Fragment.getChildFragmentManager() when instantiating the FragmentPagerAdapter. Also note that you cannot use Fragment.setRetainInstance() on the children fragments or you'll get an exception.